# syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I wrote a method and I received an error. This is my code :

```
def workouts_number
  @workout_block = BlockWorkout.all
  @number = Hash.new(0)

  @workout_block.each do |record|
    @current_workout_block = BlockWorkout.group(:workout_id).order(COUNT(workout_id) DESC).limit(5)
    @name = @current_workout_block['block_name']
    @number[@name] += 1
  end

  render :json => {data: {unprocessed: @workout_block, processed: @number}}
end
```

Then I received this error message :

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<SyntaxError: /home/gabriel_rc/Área de Trabalho/Atlas/atlas-academia-back/app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb:146: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'\n...d).order(COUNT(workout_id) DESC).limit(5)\n...                           ^~~~\n/home/gabriel_rc/Área de Trabalho/Atlas/atlas-academia-back/app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb:174: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input>",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
      {
        "exception_object_id": 27087800,
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb:146: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'"
      },
```

It says that occured a Syntax error at line 146. Line 146 as follows :

```
@current_workout_block = BlockWorkout.group(:workout_id).order(COUNT(workout_id) DESC).limit(5)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Be careful, `order` method take a symbol or a string as argument ! You are trying to pass something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add quotes around your SQL snippet so that is is handled as a String by Ruby.

```
@current_workout_block = BlockWorkout.group(:workout_id).order("COUNT(workout_id) DESC").limit(5)
```

Comment: Prefer single quotes to match with Rubocop